# If someone has my private keys can I delete that and all permissions it may have?

Tags: ssh

If someone has my private keys can I delete that and all permissions it may have? Then generate a new key and ask for permissions for everything my ssh key has access to?

Answer (score 0):

It depends ;-) If you still have access to all systems, where your public key is in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file, then I would do the following

1. generate a new public/private key pair
2. login with your old private key to the systems
3. remove the old public key from the `.ssh/authorized_keys`
4. add your new public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys`
5. test access with your new private key

If you don't have the possibility to change the public key on the remote systems yourself, ask the administrator to do that for you and to remove your old public key.

In any case you should check if the remote systems are compromised.